# Saving my ActiveRecord model deletes my CarrierWave image versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rails-activerecord

Whenever I save a model with a mounted uploader, the versions get deleted whenever I save it (and it appears as if the versions are not even created when uploading an image normally). Note that it used to work fine until a few days/weeks ago (I didn't notice the exact time although it may have happened by moving to Rails 3.2.11. I was at 3.2.8 before).

My model is defined like this:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :profile_picture
  mount_uploader :profile_picture, ProfilePictureUploader
  ...
end
```

And my `ProfilePictureUploader`:

```
class ProfilePictureUploader < BaseUploader
  process :resize_to_fill => [248, 248]

  version :tiny do
    process :resize_to_fill => [34, 34]
    def full_filename(for_file = model.photo.file)
      "#{model.to_s.parameterize}_tiny.jpg"
    end
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    # John Snow -> john-snow-20120913162935.jpg
    # ACME inc. -> acme-inc-20120913162935.png
    "#{model.to_s.parameterize}-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}#{File.extname(original_filename)}" if original_filename
  end
end
```

And finally my `BaseUploader`:

```
class BaseUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  def store_dir
    "system/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  def filename
    "#{mounted_as}#{File.extname(original_filename)}" if original_filename
  end
end
```

I use file store in development and fog storage in production, but the issue occurs in both environments so let's just assume it's using file storage.

Here's my typical scenario:

- I upload an image to a Profile, only the standard image gets created (ex: `mbillard-20130122102833.jpg`).
- I call `recreate_versions!` on the profile picture, both the standard image and the tiny version get created (the standard is recreated because of my particular naming scheme, I'm fine with that).
- I save my model, everything in the folder (`system/uploads/profile/1/`) gets deleted except the image with the filename of the `profile_picture` attribute.

I use carrierwave 0.8.0. I believe it has to do with a save trigger, but couldn't figure it out by looking at the code.

(I have also opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/961) in parallel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Basically, it seems like the `remove_previously_stored_#{column}` method in `mount.rb` removed my newly created versions because they had the same name as the previous versions.

I modified my tiny version filename to include the timestamp (so that it wouldn't have the same filename as the previous tiny version):

```
version :tiny do
  process :resize_to_fill => [34, 34]
  def full_filename(for_file = model.photo.file)
    "#{model.to_s.parameterize}_#{timestamp}_tiny.jpg"
  end
end
```

I simplified my `filename` logic to simple define a filename with the timestamp:

```
# Override the filename of the uploaded files:
# Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
def filename
  # John Snow -> john-snow-20120913162935.jpg
  # ACME inc. -> acme-inc-20120913162935.png

  "#{model.to_s.parameterize}-#{timestamp}#{File.extname(original_filename)}" if original_filename.present?
end
```

And my timestamp functions either extracts the timestamp from the filename or generates a new one when recreating versions or uploading a new file (when original_filename is present):

```
protected

def timestamp
  if original_filename.blank?
    match_data = /^.+-(\d{14})\.\D{3,4}$/.match(File.basename(model.read_attribute(mounted_as)))

    return match_data[1] if match_data
  end

  var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
  model.instance_variable_get(var) || model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
end
```

Note that the previous timestamp could be stored in an attribute on my model, but this works for me.

The only thing that annoys me now is that I have to save my model in order for the previous files to be deleted when recreating versions.

```
model.recreate_versions! # recreates versions but leaves the previous files there
model.save # removes the previous files
```

You can see my whole thought process over at the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/961).